# Adjust vertical space before enumerated list in Beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, enumerate, itemize

In Beamer, I can easily set the desired vertical space between items in an enumerated list with `itemsep`. But how do I set the vertical space between the line that introduces the enumerated list and the first item in this list? Ideally I would like it to be identical to the space between the items in the list. In the MWE below, I want more space after the itemized line "Here are two interesting things:"

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Here are two interesting things:
            \begin{enumerate} \itemsep2ex
                \item This is number one.
                \item And this is number two.
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply setting `\topsep` as is usual does not work in the beamer case.  Instead you can redefine `\@listii` as follows:

[image: Sample outptu]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatletter
\def\@listii{\leftmargin\leftmarginii
              \topsep    2ex
              \parsep    0\p@   \@plus\p@
              \itemsep   \parsep}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Here are two interesting things:
            \begin{enumerate} \itemsep2ex
                \item This is number one.
                \item And this is number two.
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

See the file `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty` where you will find the formatting variables `\@listi`, `\@listii` and `\@listiii` for formatting of lists at depths one, two and three, respectively.

You can define macro that will set `\topsep`, `\itemsep` to the same value (`#2`) for lists of a given level as in the example below.  This is particularly useful you want to scope the change of definition for just a single frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setlistspacing}[2]{\def\@ld{#1}\expandafter\def\csname
@list\romannumeral\@ld \endcsname{\leftmargin\csname
leftmargin\romannumeral\@ld \endcsname
              \topsep    #2
              \parsep    0\p@   \@plus\p@
              \itemsep   #2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
{\setlistspacing{2}{2ex}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Here are two interesting things:
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item This is number one.
    \item And this is number two.
    \end{enumerate}
  \item Here are no interesting things.
  \item Here are two interesting things:
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item This is number one.
    \item And this is number two.
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
}

{\setlistspacing{1}{4ex}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Here are two interesting things:
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item This is number one.
    \item And this is number two.
    \end{enumerate}
  \item Here are no interesting things.
  \item Here are two interesting things.
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item This is number one.
    \item And this is number two.
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Here are two interesting things:
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item This is number one.
    \item And this is number two.
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document
```

}

[image: Sample output]

Comment: One problem here is that I want some flexibility with respect to what the distance is. On another slide, for example, I might want the distance to be ``1ex``.

Comment: You can put the code from my preamble just before the frame and enclose everything in a `\bgroup / \egroup` pair.  Then it is just that frame that is affected.